# Disable CTS flow control on windows COM port

Tags: c++, windows, serial-port

I am using [SetCommState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setcommstate) to configure a COM port.

```
        if (!BuildCommDCBA(
                 "baud=9600 parity=N data=8 stop=1",
                &dcbSerialParams))
            return;
        SetCommState(myCOMHandle, &dcbSerialParams);
```

This appears to enable the CTS flow control, which my hardware does not support

```
        _COMMCONFIG cfg;
        DWORD sz = sizeof(cfg);
        if (!GetCommConfig(
                myCOMHandle, // Handle to the Serial port
                &cfg,
                &sz))
            std::cout << "GetCommConfig FAILED\n";
        DCB dcb = cfg.dcb;
        std::cout << "\nBaudRate " << dcb.BaudRate
                  << "\nfBinary " << dcb.fBinary
                  << "\nfParity " << dcb.fParity
                  << "\nfOutxCtsFlow " << dcb.fOutxCtsFlow ...
```

outputs

```
BaudRate 9600
fBinary 1
fParity 0
fOutxCtsFlow 1
```

I have tried using

```
"baud=9600 parity=N data=8 stop=1 octs=off"
```

but this gives the same result.

I have also tried over-writing the output from BuildCommDCBA

dcbSerialParams.fOutxCtsFlow = 0;

```
        if (!BuildCommDCBA(
                 "baud=9600 parity=N data=8 stop=1",
                &dcbSerialParams))
            return;
        dcbSerialParams.fOutxCtsFlow = 0;
        SetCommState(myCOMHandle, &dcbSerialParams);
```

but this also gives the same result.

The documentation for [BuildCommDCBA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-buildcommdcba) says this

> There are older and newer forms of the mode syntax. The BuildCommDCB
> function supports both forms. However, you cannot mix the two forms
> together.
>
> The newer form of the mode syntax lets you explicitly set the values
> of the flow control members of the DCB structure. If you use an older
> form of the mode syntax, the BuildCommDCB function sets the flow
> control members of the DCB structure,

This certainly seems to have something to do with my problem.  However I cannot find a description of the newer and older forms of the mode syntax.  I have looked at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mode).

Can I assume I am using the newer from?  Why is the fOutxCtsFlow being set?  How can I force it to unset?

Comment: Set it manually? `dcbSerialParams.fOutxCtsFlow = FALSE;` And probably `dcbSerialParams.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE;` too.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried it,  Doesn't work.  See details in edited question.

Comment: I tried your code and got strange results until I initialized: `DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };` I guess `BuildCommDCBA` doesn't set all the fields, which the docs mention: _The BuildCommDCB function adjusts only those members of the DCB structure that are specifically affected by the lpDef parameter..._

Comment: @JohnnyMopp  That did it!  Post as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Instead of `DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };`, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setcommstate#remarks) recommends to first call `GetCommConfig()`, then modify the relevant fields and then call `SetCommConfig()`.

Comment: @Codo  That seems like a bad idea.  Who knows what weird settings might be in effect!  I would have to write explicit code for every one of the numerous attributes to ensure they were sensible.  Much better to initialize everything to zero in one line.

Comment: As far as I understand you get fresh default values when you open the device, not the last settings using by some other program. Better check first that 0 is a sensible value for all fields you don't touch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-buildcommdcba#remarks):

> The BuildCommDCB function adjusts only those members of the DCB structure that are specifically affected by the lpDef parameter...

So you need to make sure all the other fields have acceptable values. The simplest way is to just initialize with

```
DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };
```

This should disable all flow control by setting all pertinent values to `FALSE` or `0`. As long as your string sets all the other important stuff (baud rate, parity, stop bits, and data size) this should be ok. In particular, you will get:

```
fBinary = FALSE;
fNull = FALSE;
fErrorChar = FALSE;
fParity = FALSE;
fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE;
fOutxCtsFlow = FALSE;
fOutX = FALSE;
fInX = FALSE;
fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE;
fOutxDsrFlow = FALSE;
```

Another option is to initialize the fields by calling one of

- [`GetCommConfig()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcommconfig) - *Retrieves the current configuration of a communications device.*
- [`GetDefaultCommConfigA()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getdefaultcommconfiga) - *Retrieves the default configuration for the specified communications device.*
- [`GetCommState()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcommstate) - *Retrieves the current control settings for a specified communications device.*